# uninitialized value in regex compilation in perl

Tags: regex, perl, if-statement, initialization

The below code is giving an error when I use if-else block for the comparison of $valid. When if-else condition is not used the error is not there. The error is " Use of uninitialized value $value in regexp compilation".How to solve this?

```
...
if($valid eq 1){
print "Enter value\n" ;
my $value = <STDIN>;
}else{
  print " valid is not 1 \n";
}
if($line =~ /$string.*$value/){  --> error
    //code
}
```

Comment: What's the scope of a variable declared with `my`?

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: Is **$valid** stores a digit or string value? Operation **eq** applies to strings, but after **eq** you have a digit.

https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/PERL/node37.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Perl program needs `(pragma: A pragma is a module which influences some aspect of the compile time or run time behaviour of Perl, such as strict or warnings)`. Unless until we see the full code.
2. Please understand the declaration of the variables inside the block and outside of the block.

> Coming to your code:

```
 if($valid eq 1)
 {
      print "Enter value\n" ;
      my $value = <STDIN>;
      #This the "$value" prints what you have get from the MS-Dos Prompt from the user.
      #$value ends here since the $value has been declared this block
 }
```

$value needs to declare outside the `if-else` block you won't get the error message.

```
 my $value = "";
 if($valid eq 1)
 {
      print "Enter value\n" ;
      $value = <STDIN>;
      chomp($value); #Additionally, you should chomp (remove the entermark at end of the value $value;
 }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I took some liberty to alter your code to make it work 
[enter **dog** or **cat** at the prompt for a test]

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $valid = '1';
my $value;

my $line    = 'Some lazy dog is taking a sun bath';
my $string  = 'lazy';

if($valid eq '1'){
    print "Enter value: " ;
    $value = <STDIN>;
    chomp $value;
}else{
    print " valid is not 1 \n";
}

if( $line =~ /$string.*$value/ ){  
    print 'Horay!!! I found the string - ';
    print "$line\n";
} else {
    print "Sorry, no line found\n";
}
```

Your error is hidden in scope declaration of **$value** -- it is only valid for **if** internal block of code - I have moved it outside of **if ... else ...** block.

NOTE: perhaps you intended to write

```
my $valid = 1;
....
if( $valid ) {
   ....
} else {
   ....
}
```

although the following code is valid but in this particular case is excessive (if **$valid** is **not zero** it considered **true**)

```
if( $valid == 1 ) {
   ....
} else {
   ....
}
```

[Comparison operators for numbers and strings](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/PERL/node37.html)